# match possible letters with numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Been searching for an answer without obvious success.

I have a post data check in place using preg_match for posted value of QR12345678. The QR may or may not be submitted. I've used the various preg_match below with no luck.

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{4,10}$/', $_POST['some_id'])
preg_match('/^[A-Z]{1,3}?[0-9]{4,10}$/', $_POST['some_id'])
preg_match('/([A-Z]{1,3})?[0-9]{4,10}$/', $_POST['some_id'])
preg_match('/^([A-Z]{1,3})?[0-9]{4,10}$/', $_POST['some_id'])
preg_match('/[A-Z]{0,3}[0-9]{4,10}/', $_POST['some_id'])
preg_match('/([A-Z]{1,3})*[0-9]{4,10}$/', $_POST['some_id'])
```

using `preg_match` in the following inline condition

```
 $some_id = isset($_POST['some_id']) 
        && preg_match('/[A-Z]{1,3}*[0-9]{4,10}/', $_POST['some_id'])
    ? $_POST['some_id']
    : 0;
```

So, `$some_id` returns `0` no matter what.

Comment: `/^([A-Z]{1,3})?[0-9]{4,10}$/` should work, what is the problem?

Comment: any 2 letters followed by 8 numbers? bounded by ?

Comment: Could you describe the allowed patterns more clearly? Is it either 2 letters or none? Or are 1 or 3 letter allowed as well?

Comment: var_dump(preg_match('/^([A-Z]{1,3})?([0-9]{4,10})$/', 'QR12345678'));
    var_dump(preg_match('/^([A-Z]{1,3})?([0-9]{4,10})$/', '12345678'));

Both throw a match. But don't you want {1,2} after the first one?

Comment: 4 to 10 numbers with or without 1 to 3 letters in front of the numbers.

Comment: @spiderling And where does the regex highlighted by anubhava fail that?

Comment: @kingkero - my updated post show how I am using the preg_match and that it is returning 0 not what I tried. Even anubhava suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the pattern that you're actually using in your code:

```
> echo preg_match('/[A-Z]{1,3}*[0-9]{4,10}/',"QR12345678");
< PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 10 in php shell code on line 1
```

The part that doesn't work is `{1,3}*` where you have 2 quantifiers right after each other and the second one (`*`) doesn't know what to repeat. Either remove the redundant `*` quantifier or use one of the other suggested patterns:

```
> echo preg_match('/[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{4,10}/',"QR12345678");
< 1
> echo preg_match('/^([A-Z]{1,3})?([0-9]{4,10})$/',"QR12345678");
< 1
```

Comment: Using the second one for my situation